# My Through Table is Pulling the wrong Active Records Assocations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I'm working on a sample Rails app that has Users, Events (that the user creates) and ultimately, Users will be able to subscribe / attend these events.

I'm a the point where I need to create a through table to track the event_ids and user_ids of the attendees of these events. While I think it's set up correctly, when I query the database, through a User, instead of getting the Event ActiveRecords, I get the User Active Records.

```
 testUser = User.find(4)
 testUser.events_to_attend
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "attendees" ON "users"."id" = "attendees"."user_id" WHERE "attendees"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 4]]

 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 4, name: "Steve Bear", email: "steve@bear.com", password: nil, password_confirmation: nil, created_at: "2016-09-01 21:20:08", updated_at: "2016-09-01 21:20:08", password_digest: "$2a$10$iytkAI9EmrmCG6aRsvK13.50ssBxWs.i5G1T1HjgPQz...">, #<User id: 4, name: "Steve Bear", email: "steve@bear.com", password: nil, password_confirmation: nil, created_at: "2016-09-01 21:20:08", updated_at: "2016-09-01 21:20:08", password_digest: "$2a$10$iytkAI9EmrmCG6aRsvK13.50ssBxWs.i5G1T1HjgPQz...">]>
```

From this is see that I'm not making the correct SQL call but I'm not sure how to configure this to I pull the Event Records that the User is associated with?

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attendees
  has_many :events_to_attend, through: :attendees, source: :user

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 225}, format: {:with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, presence: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true

end
```

attendee.rb

```
class Attendee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm happy to list my migrations should that be helpful to anyone

Comment: `has_many :events_to_attend, through: :attendees, source: :user` that's because you're telling it to fetch the user: `source: :user`. Try `source: :event` and see what happens :)

Comment: Ahhh. Fixed!! Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have...

```
  has_many :events_to_attend, through: :attendees, source: :user
```

I think you wanted events, not users...

```
  has_many :events_to_attend, through: :attendees, source: :event
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you. For some reason (probably my own fault) this didn't work last night.

Comment: Glad I could help!  If you found the answer useful, feel free to "accept" it (the option is on the left of my answer).